# Custom Plugin for WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a plugin for to combine WooCommerce Subscriptions & WooCommerce Account Funds, the aim is that when a member upgrades to "Gold Member" they get credited £40 and they continue to get credited every 28 days thereafter as long as their subscription is active.

The problem I have is that as soon as someone puts a standard order through, they get credited for £40! I'm unsure why this is happening! also I cant get it to reoccur every 28 days. heres my code.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: WooCommerce Subscriptions Funds
Plugin URI: 
Description: Combined WooCommerce Subscriptions & WooCommerce Funds
Version: 1.0
Author: Brad Houston
Author URI: 
License: GPL
*/

/**
 * Required functions
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'woothemes_queue_update' ) || ! function_exists( 'is_woocommerce_active' ) ) {
    require_once( 'woo-includes/woo-functions.php' );
}

/**
 * Check if WooCommerce is active, and if it isn't, disable Subscriptions.
 *
 * @since 1.0
 */
if ( ! is_woocommerce_active() || version_compare( get_option( 'woocommerce_db_version' ), '2.1', '<' ) ) {
    add_action( 'admin_notices', 'WC_Subscriptions::woocommerce_inactive_notice' );
    return;
}

class WC_Subscriptions_Funds
{
    /**
     * Bootstraps the class and hooks required actions & filters.
     *
     * @since 1.0
     */
    public static function init(){
        // Check if we want to create the order ourself (a renewal order)
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_create_order', __CLASS__ . '::filter_woocommerce_create_order', 10, 2 );
    }

    public static function filter_woocommerce_create_order( $order_id, $checkout_object ) {
        global $woocommerce;

        $customer_id = get_current_user_id();
        WC_Account_Funds::add_funds( $customer_id, 40 );
        //var_dump($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents);exit;

        return $order_id;
    }
}

WC_Subscriptions_Funds::init();
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `woocommerce_create_order` hook doesn't mean the order is successful, or paid for, it's just been added to the database.

What you want to do is check whether or not the order is completed.

There's a bunch of hooks for order status changes (c.f. http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html and http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#2138)

So, looking at those docs, and checking for a completed status hook, you probably want to respond to `woocommerce_order_status_completed`.

Also, `get_current_user_id();` is the wrong way to get the order's customer. If you're using bank transfer payment, the "current user id" will likely be the admin that marks the order as completed, not the customer. I *think* WC_Order has a `get_user_id()` or `get_user()` method to do that – check the docs or source.

Comment: @BradHouston you seem to get by php ok but the intricacies of both Wordpress and WooCommerce are a challenge of their own.